# Java regex for max length with one hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate an input based on given condition,

-must be total length of 20 characters
-first five position must be alphabets
-remaining should be numbers but must exists one hyphen(-) which should occur between the numbers only.
I have the regex like

```
([a-zA-Z]){5}[0-9]+([-]){15}
```

but it allows the hyphen at the end as well and even accepts without hyphen.

Comment: So why didn't you put a hyphen *inside* number pattern?

Comment: I think it's simpler to try a non-regex solution here.

Comment: Yes, I did put the hyphen inside but the effect is same. I just added the above one because that was my last test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z]{5}(?=[0-9-]{15}$)[0-9]+-[0-9]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT0xK8/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]{5}` - matches 5 letters
- `(?=[0-9-]{15}$)` - requires that the rest of the string should be  15 chars long
- `[0-9]+-[0-9]+` - 1+ digits followed with a hyphen, followed with 1+ digit
- `$` - end of string (you may replace with `\z` to exclude matching before the last newline at the end of the string)

If you use `.matches()`, you may omit the outer anchors.

See the [Java test](http://ideone.com/Kp8g06):

```
String pat = "[a-zA-Z]{5}(?=[0-9-]{15}$)[0-9]+-[0-9]+"; 
System.out.println("abcde123456-89012345".matches(pat));   // true
System.out.println("abcde-12345689012345".matches(pat));   // false
System.out.println("abcde12345689012345-".matches(pat));   // false
System.out.println("abcde12345689012345-12".matches(pat)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add the non-regex perspective here:

```
if (str.length() != 20) {
  return false;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  if (!Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i)) {
    return false;
  }
}
boolean hyphenFound = false;
for (int i = 5; i < 20; ++i) {
  char ch = str.charAt(i);
  if (ch == '-') {
    hyphenFound = true;
  } else if (!Character.isDigit(ch) && !Character.isAlphabetic(ch)) {
    return false;
  }
}
return hyphenFound;
```